# Attempting to load a "div" as dynamic content is returned

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a PHP program which performs a series of key driven SSH connections (as Apache user www-data), and executes scripts on the remote server which check the statuses of a couple services/deamons.  Based on the reported status, "Running" or "Stopped," a function determines the appropriate image, green check or red 'x', that should be display within a div table cell.

It looks like this:

[image: service status screen capture]

The problem is 9 servers are polled and 18 div table cells are dynamically built.  I'd like to refresh/display each div as the data is returned from each SSH call.

This is the PHP code where each SSH call is made the div containing the result is inserted:

```
           $cmd_string=buildServiceCallString($distIP, "VolCreationService","serviceCheck");

            echo "<div class=\"statTableRow\">";
        echo "<div class=\"statData statTableCell\">";
            $cmd_output=shell_exec($cmd_string);
            echo "<span class=\"serviceTitle\">VolCreationService: <img class=\"runStatImage\" src=\"".displayRunStatusImage($cmd_output)."\"></span>";
            $cmd_output="";
                   echo "</div>"; //end statTableCell
                   echo "</div>"; //end statTableRow
```

I've made an effort to understand the jQuery .load() method, but it hasn't clicked yet.  I imagine this will involve a callback, but I don't understand how the element is accessed and displayed with an asynchronous call.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

-TU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a very simple example of how to dynamically add content to a DOM element. You can use $.ajax

```
 var request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.php",
      data: data_obj,
      dataType: "html"
   }).done(function(msg) {
         $("#example_element").append(msg);
      }
```

the url: will point to your file.

data: is optional, but using that option will allow you to pass the key you want to retrieve back.

dataType: specifies what return type you expect

in .done the simplest thing you can do to load content is just to append it to something (or replace, but in your case you probably want to append it).

Note that this call doesn't check for error cases.

[The documentation is pretty verbose but you should still read it if you plan on using AJAX calls.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I'm still totally lost here...It seems that script is executed after everything is loaded.  Am I approaching this incorrectly?  I would like to load the page cell by cell as the information is returned from an ssh call...

Comment: Let's say you have a div named example_element. What this call will do is go to a php file called example.php and expect the return value to be html. Once the AJAX call is finished the .done portion of the call will then append whatever html value example.php returned to the div element named example_element.

Comment: Does your php script return it's data after every ssh call has finished?

Comment: Thanks a million!  I could not get the $.ajax call to behave quite like I wanted to.  It was in a loop and needed to make multiple calls.  I could only get one response.  I suppose it is my learning curve here this is blocking success with that call.  At any rate, I tried the .load() method, that allows me specify the same parameters, but make multiple requests and receive multiple responses.  My script was not returning anything before.  Your tip guided me to correcting that, and reading the documentation helped me understand a little better.  Thanks again.