# update div with Ajax MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to understand how to update a div of items after a category is selected. I've got this far and am now confused. How to get the values from the view into the controller to make the query?

```
 //get <li> clicked and display the items in that category
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#test li').click(function() {
    var selector = "input[name='" + $(this).id + "value']";
    var catID = $(selector).val(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        type: "get",
        data: {//return all the item info},
        success: function(data) {
            //update div contents here?

        }
    });
});
});
```

Partial to be updated upon which category is clicked

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {

    <ul>

        <li>@item.item_name</li>
        <li><input type="hidden" class="item_id" value="@item.ID" /></li>

    </ul>

 }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult PartialTwo( int id)//how to pass category id?
    {

        var query = from d in db.Items
                    where d.catId==id
                    orderby d.dateAdded
                    select d;
        var results = query;


        return PartialView("_FullInfoPartial", results);
        //returns items in the clicked category  

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of two **li**

```
<li>@item.item_name</li>
<li><input type="hidden" class="item_id" value="@item.ID" /></li>
```

you can just use one in order to decrease dom size if it is not required

```
<li data-id="@item.ID">@item.item_name</li>
```

and you can get the partial view result with **$.get** easily

```
$("#test li").on("click",function(){

    var requestPage = "/PartialTwo?id=" + $(this).data("id");
    $.get(requestPage, function(result){
        $("#content").html(result); // where you want to put the result
    });
});
```

Comment: yes! this is what I've been trying to figure out. So I don't need all the AjaxOptions then, like data, datatype etc?

Comment: No, actually it depends on requirements but if you just want to load html result from url you don't need that

Comment: DO you know Where can I find out more about this? It seems every tutorial only talks about ajax actionlinks and forms. I can't seem to find this type of material

Comment: No, I'm sorry I don't know any particular material about it. However, you don't need to use that helpers you can handle as you desired through jQuery if you know enough.

Comment: ok thanks. One more thing. Should I add the controller to the front of the url request? 
`var requestPage = "Item/PartialTwo?id=" + $(this).data("id");`

Comment: Of course, I didn't know the name of controller therefore I've just written action so It should be **var requestPage = "/Item/PartialTwo?id=" + $(this).data("id");**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35555/discussion-between-healix-and-gokhan-girgin)

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a very similar question over here, though the example was using PHP. The basic idea is the same however. your MVC4 will return some data type that will be turned into HTML (the easiest way is to just return straight HTML) and then you will append this HTML value to a DOM element (in this case, the div item of your choice).

the JQuery would look similar too:

```
var request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.php",
      data: data_obj,
      dataType: "html"
   }).done(function(msg) {
         $("#example_element").append(msg);
      }
```

[Attempting to load a "div" as dynamic content is returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138005/attempting-to-load-a-div-as-dynamic-content-is-returned/18138124#18138124)

Comment: so when I call the function in my controller to filter the results the id from the ajax gets passed?
this `var catID = $(selector).val(); ` get passed into this 
`public ActionResult PartialTwo( int id)` and can I use InsertionMode to replace? Still new to AJAX

Comment: Ahh, my apologises. Your title made me think you were at the ajax portion of this problem. Are you asking how to get the catID to your query?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax.BeginForm` as follows,

`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "youDivId" }))`

Using the above and making your controller returning `Patial View` will update your div with the `partial view result`.